# To which year back in time was Hawkeye sent during the test run for the Time Heist?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, when the test run for the Time Heist is conducted, Scott Lang drops out as he felt nervous. Clint, at the time, volunteers.

It's quite apparent that Clint was sent to a pre-Snap time. However, is there any indication as to which exact year (and/or date) he was sent to?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any official answer on this. The closest we can do is guesstimate based on Lila's looks between the 2018 version of her at the start of *Avengers: Endgame* (Image 1) and the version we see in the test run (Image 2).

[image: Clint positions Lila squaring her shoulders off whilst stood behind her to take a better shot with the bow; they are stood in front of the barn]

[image: The camera looks through the window of the Barton home, Lila is seen leaning on the door frame looking out for her dad]

To me there doesn't appear to be much of an age difference but the test run version does appear to be a little bit younger. However, with not too much of a visible age gap between them at most this was two years (and that's pushing it) prior to the opening scene. This would mean he was sent back to anytime in 2016 - 2018.

She also doesn't seem too fazed that Clint is there and given that he was home during these 2 years on house arrest that makes sense. Before that he would have been constantly coming and going as we see in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* so that's the small window he was likely there.

It's also worth noting that Lila is played by Ava Russo<sup>1</sup> in every scene she appears in. So whilst they could have made her look younger or slightly older they didn't alter things too much so it's unlikely this was too many years out from 2018.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>*Fun fact [she is Joe Russo's daughter](https://twitter.com/russo_brothers/status/1254908589409353728?lang=en): "This is Joe’s daughter, Ava, playing Lila Barton. AND @JeremyRenner’s actual daughter’s name is Ava, so spot on casting there… #AvengersAssemble"*</sub>

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot You're right! The dead give away is your point on Lila's reaction to her father's call. If he was away, she would've sounded excited/surprised. The tone of her response says he was at home during the time. Thus, truly after the *AoU* and obviously before the Snap.

Comment: dang, missed opportunity for the hashtag "#AVAngersAssemble"